# How to initialize compound type?

Tags: scala

I have a type definition with customized trait:

```
trait Foo {
  def bar: String
}

val BooleanType: Class[Boolean] with Foo = classOf[Boolean] with Foo {
  def bar = ""
}

//Error: error: ';' expected but 'with' found.
```

However this does not work. I also tried:

```
val BooleanType: Class[Boolean] with Foo = classOf[Boolean] {...}
//Error:  Class[Boolean](classOf[scala.Boolean]) does not take parameters
```

and

```
val BooleanType: Class[Boolean] with Foo = classOf[Boolean] with new Foo {...}
//Error:  error: ';' expected but 'with' found.
```

None works. How can this be achieved?

---

Edit: I also tried with scala Type:

```
val Boolean: Type with Foo = typeOf[Boolean] with Foo {...}
//error: ';' expected but 'with' found.
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you are closer to right thing but you can't extend primitive types like `Boolean` or `Long`. Also you won't need `classOf[]` just `extends X with Y`

Comment: @prayagupd I am not extending primitive types. I am extending `Class` class

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say "this does not work" and "How can this be achieved", but you never explain what "this" *is* and *what* you want to achieve, and it is also not obvious from your code.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I am trying to create Type objects with custom traits so it acts as meta data to transport between server and clients. I could just use string, but i wish to create relationship between scala type and the meta representation without having to do a lot of match/case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a subclass of `Class` because it is a final class. If you could, and if it had a constructor, the syntax would be:

```
val BooleanType: Class[Boolean] with Foo = new Class[Boolean](< args >) with Foo {
  def bar = ""
}
```

As far as I know it's not possible to subclass a specific instance (like you're trying to do with `classOf[Boolean]`).

Comment: Could you take a look at my edit? I tried with scala Type which is not final, but still does not work

Comment: See the last part of this answer - you're not _instantiating_ a new value, you're trying to extend an _already-instantiated_ value (`classOf[...]` returns an instance of `Class` - it's not a constructor call) which is impossible (just like writing `5 with Foo`). As far as I can see, yhe only way to achieve what you're trying to do (adding a `bar` method to `Class[Boolean]`) is with implicits, using the ["enhance my library" pattern](https://coderwall.com/p/k_1jzw/scala-s-pimp-my-library-pattern-example).